# Does $V_n$ model union?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I'm seeking a finite model of union, and in particular I would like to show that $V_n \vDash$ union. As usual, I have defined $V_0 = \emptyset$ and $V_n = {\cal P}(V_{n-1})$ for $n \in \omega$. Have I made a mistake in this proof?

Proof. Pick $x \in V_n$. Show $\bigcup x \in V_n$, or rather $\bigcup x \subseteq V_{n-1}$.

Since $x \in V_n$ this means that $x \subseteq V_{n-1}$. Therefore $\bigcup x \subseteq \bigcup V_{n-1} = V_{n-2} \subseteq V_{n-1}$.

Comment: "The last equality follows from $∪V_m=V_m$, i.e. the union does not expand $V_m$", take $V_1=\{\emptyset\}$, then $a\in\cup V_1\iff a\in b\in V_1\iff a\in\emptyset \implies \cup V_1=\emptyset\ne V_1$. In general, $\bigcup {\cal P}(A)=A\ne {\cal P}(A)$, so $\bigcup V_{n+1}=V_n$

Comment: Ahh. I made a mistake in my corollary (which I didn't post). It is just not true that the union doesn't expand $V_n$. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is true. I would just argue in terms of rank directly. Any element of $\cup x$ is at least two ranks less than $x,$ so $\cup x$ has lower rank than $x.$

Comment: Given @Holo 's remark: $x \subseteq V_{n-1} \Rightarrow \cup x \subseteq V_{n-2} \subseteq V_{n-1}$. And this proves it.